# Calculate difference in hours PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write a PHP code to count publishing time-lapse. I have a date and time in this format: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 12:45:09 GMT ($pub_time).

My code:

```
$timestamp=  strtotime($pub_time) ;
$minutes = floor((strtotime('now') - $timestamp)/ 60);
if  ($minutes < 60) {
    return $time_string = $minutes . ' minutes ago';
} else {
    return $time_string = floor(($minutes) / 60) . ' hours ago';
}
```

As a result I need to get smth like this : "4 hours ago".

Using my code I get this result - 420104.58333333 hours ago, whatever input date there is. Any thoughts?

Comment: I get the expected result, at the moment of writing 19.9hours: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6f75d3281961bdb8a0e1cd4f4efcc693e1b593d

Comment: I rolled your answer back, as the rounding may actually provide some info. Like a `floor()` in the wrong place :)

Comment: [Why reinvent the wheel when someone has already done it?](https://github.com/jimmiw/php-time-ago)

Comment: If you expected 4 and output is 420104.58333333, then divide by 100000 and then floor your answer and then test, this method of testing may lead to wrong answers but sometimes it also works

Comment: OK, i think i found my problem, i had a wrong input date variable. thanks anyway,  Martijn ) May be my code will be useful for anyone, so leave it here.

Comment: why is `floor` inside? it should be wrapping the arithmetic inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class build in php and do it like that:

```
$time = 'Sun, 03 Dec 2017 12:25:09 GMT';
$oldTime = new DateTime($time);
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$difference = $oldTime->diff($now);

$hours = $difference->h;
$minutes = $difference->i;
$days = $difference->d;
```

from here you build your logic to display as you wish.